# Recent developments in the diagnosis of Parkinson's Disease

Tags: biotechnology, biomedical-engineering, neurodegenerative-disorders

I was reading a research paper titled - "[Discovery of Volatile Biomarkers of Parkinson’s Disease from Sebum](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acscentsci.8b00879)" by Drupad K. Trivedi. I am Providing a short summary of it.

> Discovery of Volatile Biomarkers of Parkinson’s Disease from Sebum

`Parkinson's disease (PD) is a neurodegenerative disease that is difficult to diagnose early. However, a "Super Smeller" individual was discovered who can detect PD by odor alone. Early studies showed that the odor was present in the sebum (skin oil) of PD subjects. In this study, the volatile metabolites of sebum samples from control subjects and PD subjects were analyzed using thermal desorption-gas chromatography-mass spectrometry (TD-GC-MS) and validated by a separate group. The results identified a distinct volatiles-associated signature of PD, including altered levels of perillic aldehyde and eicosane. The odor of these compounds was confirmed by the "Super Smeller" to be highly similar to the scent of PD. Additionally, the study used machine learning approaches to validate the biomarkers. Further analysis showed that the compounds eicosane, perillic aldehyde, hippuric acid, and octadecanal were consistent and differentially expressed between PD and control samples. The presence of these biomarkers was confirmed by the "Super Smeller" through qualitative smell analysis. The study also demonstrated that these biomarkers were not associated with medication use in PD subjects. The findings suggest that analysis of volatile metabolites in sebum could potentially be used as a non-invasive screening method for PD. However, further research with a larger sample size is needed to validate the results and understand the underlying mechanisms of PD-associated odor.`

I have read several research papers on this topic, but I am still unclear about the accuracy of these compounds for detecting Parkinson's disease and whether they have been validated in other experiments. I would greatly appreciate guidance from someone with more knowledge on this subject. As part of my college club, I need to write an article on this, and it would be helpful to have more insights.

Comment: So - you are at college and you have done the relevant literature search and looked at the paper's references? And what did they say?

Comment: Have you searched for relevant papers which _cite_ the Trivedi et al. paper?  A basic such search is easy to do with Google Scholar.  Was the Sinclair 2021 _Nature_ paper of any help?

Comment: A small point: the problem with PD isn't so much with the diagnosis as the treatment, although clearly, any approach to treatment may be enhanced by some understanding of the possible implication of these volatile substances in the pathogenesis of PD itself: "the underlying mechanisms etc.''.  So, the matter is certainly worth pursuing from that angle.  Why don't you write to Trivedi himself if only to broaden your perspective?